# Nodejs python module not found after installing with Anaconda

Tags: python, node.js, anaconda, conda

I am creating a new conda env with the following command:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

After that I need to install some python modules for my project. I started with `nodejs`:

```
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

the issue I am facing is that when trying to load `nodejs` I get the following error in JupyterLab

```
import nodejs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nodejs'
```

If I check the `conda list` in `myenv` I can see that the package is actually there. So, why isnt it loaded?

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py37hcc03f2d_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.2.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h0013d47_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.4           py37hd8e9650_1    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4           py37hf50a25e_1008    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.2.1            py37hd8e9650_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        3.1.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py37h7b7c402_1    conda-forge
ipython                   5.8.0                    py37_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.0            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.2.9                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h0013d47_2    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hcc03f2d_1002    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbclient                  0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py37h03978a9_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.0.8                      py_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nodejs                    15.3.0               h57928b3_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.1.5            py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1h               he774522_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.7               pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.11.2               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       20.3.1           py37haa95532_0
prometheus_client         0.9.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                     py_1    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.7.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37hf50a25e_2    conda-forge
python                    3.7.9                h60c2a47_0
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pywin32                   228              py37h4ab8f01_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.7            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     20.0.0           py37h0d95fc2_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                51.0.0           py37haa95532_2
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
terminado                 0.9.1            py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.3                h0e60522_3    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

Comment: NodeJS is a native application not a Python module. Maybe you're thinking of [this PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/nodejs/)? In which, case you might try `pip install nodejs` (with your environment activated), since it doesn't seem to have a Conda build available. Or you can [make a Conda build of it for Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/#add_recipe).

Comment: Indeed, if I install it via pip it works but now i am wondering why is there a nodejs module in my conda list - see `nodejs                    15.3.0               h57928b3_0    conda-forge`. What is this then?

Comment: that is the actual vanilla NodeJS binary, as opposed to the Python bindings.

Comment: I am new on that, can you develop a little bit the differences between vanilla NodeJS binary and the python bindings?